# Import contacts from gmail using javascript

Tags: javascript, import-contacts

I have this following code to get the gmail contacts

```
    authParams = gapi.auth.getToken();
    authParams.alt = 'json';
    $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{my email}/full',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: authParams,
      success: function(data) { console.log('Success'); }
    });
```

But I am getting this following error

```
GET https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{my email}/full?call…tatus%5Bsigned_in%5D=true&status%5Bmethod%5D=AUTO&alt=json&_=1391506935402 401 (Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope)
```

May be I am using some old API or something like that, kindly help me out.

Comment: Hello @Uday , did u find your answer , i am stucked at the same poing not able to get the google contacts with the help of java-script . Could you help me out

Answer (score 0):

Indeed I found the answer to my question.

initially we need to add the following `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds` url to the scopes and then register to the gapi.

Here is the [link](http://geoffmcqueen.com/2010/03/14/token-invalid-authsub-token-has-wrong-scope-oauth-google-problem/) which helped me solve that issue.

And most importantly change `url` attribute from `https` to `http` in ajax request.

Comment: i am using the correct scope('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds') to get the contacts. still there is 2 kinds of errors either there is 401 unauthorization   error or the page i requested is invalid , will be grateful if u post the answer here . TY
 here is my question's link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124828/get-gmail-contacts-google-contacts-api-with-javascript

Comment: @TheDean while making the ajax call change `https` to `http`. Try changing that once in all.

Comment: tried but in vain unauthorization 401 error or invalid url still , if u have your code could u post it for me bhai  ,

Answer (score -1):

this api has a lot of restrictions (given that is under google.com instead of googleapis.com) 
I wrote this library to solve all the issues related to this.

check it out. http://eventioz.github.io/gcontacts/