# get gmail contacts Google Contacts API with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-contacts-api

it always says The page you requested is invalid. 
how can i fetch the contacts with javascript using google contacts api
i have valid scope and Client ID

```
google.load('gdata', '2.x');
    debugger
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
        if (window.location.hash == "") {
            if (!checkLogin()) {
                logMeIn();
            } else {
                var feedUrl = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full";
                query = new google.gdata.contacts.ContactQuery(feedUrl);
                query.setMaxResults(5000);
                myService = new google.gdata.contacts.ContactsService('exampleCo-exampleApp-1.0');
                myService.getContactFeed(query, function (result) {
                    document.cookie = "g314-scope-0=";
                    window.opener.parseGmailContacts(result.feed.entry);
                    close();
                }, function (e) {
                    alert(e.cause ? e.cause.statusText : e.message);
                });
            }
        }
    });
    function logMeIn() {
        scope = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds";
        var token = google.accounts.user.login(scope);
    }
    function logMeOut() {
        google.accounts.user.logout();
    }
    function checkLogin() {
        scope = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/";
        var token = google.accounts.user.checkLogin(scope);
        return token;
    }
```

i think there is something wrong with

```
  var token = google.accounts.user.checkLogin(scope);
            return token;
```

**token retuns ""(empty value here), how can i get the value of the token to get the contacts , plz help**

Comment: i think there is something wrong with
var myService = new google.gdata.contacts.ContactsService('exampleCo-exampleApp-1.0'); this

Answer (score 11):

I ran into the same problem, I solved it by first retrieving an access token, and then call the API directly. This is because the javascript api (gapi) does not support retrieving google contacts.

Since it was quite the hassle, I wrote a blogpost about it here: https://labs.magnet.me/nerds/2015/05/11/importing-google-contacts-with-javascript.html

Basically this is how I solved it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
          var clientId = 'your Client ID';
          var apiKey = 'Your API Code';
          var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly';

          $(document).on("click",".googleContactsButton", function(){
            gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
            window.setTimeout(authorize);
          });

          function authorize() {
            gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthorization);
          }

          function handleAuthorization(authorizationResult) {
            if (authorizationResult && !authorizationResult.error) {
              $.get("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/thin?alt=json&access_token=" + authorizationResult.access_token + "&max-results=500&v=3.0",
                function(response){
                  //process the response here
                  console.log(response);
                });
            }
          }
        </script>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
        <button class="googleContactsButton">Get my contacts</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works from a local HTML file but when I use it in our project in a server, I get `CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘*’`. Any ideas?

Comment: clientId and apiKey not secure in source code javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using components my friend. Life's gonna be easier and prettier.

http://googlewebcomponents.github.io/google-contacts/components/google-contacts/

Answer (score 0):

For fetching list of contacts using Google plus use this :-

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function auth() {
    var config = {
      'client_id': 'OAUTH_CLIENT_ID',
      'scope': 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds'
    };
    gapi.auth.authorize(config, function() {
      fetch(gapi.auth.getToken());
    });
  }

  function fetch(token) {
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?access_token=" + token.access_token + "&alt=json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success:function(data) {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
}
```

In the HTML Body :-

```
<button onclick="auth();">GET CONTACTS FEED</button>
```

The output will have as a field with the contact containing the phone number.

Make sure to get the client id from google developer console with proper redirect uri.

Answer (score 0):

I had slight issue with popup flashing every time the button is clicked. Adding the snippet below to Wouters solution will stop the popup window from flashing.

```
function authorize(){
    if($scope.authorizationResult){
      handleAuthorization($scope.authorizationResult);
    }else{
gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate:false}, handleAuthorization);
       } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        // Developed By: Garun Mishra.
            var clientId = 'Your Client Id';
            var apiKey = 'Your Api Key';
            var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly';

            $(document).on("click", ".getGmailContact", function () {
                gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
                window.setTimeout(authorize);
            });

            function authorize() {
                gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthorization);
            }

            function handleAuthorization(authorizationResult) {
                if (authorizationResult && !authorizationResult.error) {
                    $.get("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/thin?alt=json&access_token=" + authorizationResult.access_token + "&max-results=500&v=3.0",
                            function (response) {
                                //process the response here
                                //console.log(response);
                                var entries = response.feed.entry;
                                var contacts = [];
                                for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
                                    var contactEntry = entries[i];
                                    var contact = [];

                                    //console.log(contactEntry);
                                    // Get Full Name.
                                    if (typeof (contactEntry.gd$name) != "undefined") {
                                        if (typeof (contactEntry.gd$name.gd$fullName) != "undefined") {
                                            if (typeof (contactEntry.gd$name.gd$fullName.$t) != "undefined") {
                                                contact['name'] = contactEntry.gd$name.gd$fullName.$t;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                    // Get Phone Number
                                    if (typeof (contactEntry['gd$phoneNumber']) != "undefined") {
                                        var phoneNumber = contactEntry['gd$phoneNumber'];
                                        for (var j = 0; j < phoneNumber.length; j++) {
                                            if (typeof (phoneNumber[j]['$t']) != "undefined") {
                                                var phone = phoneNumber[j]['$t'];
                                                contact['phone'] = phone;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                    // get Email Address
                                    if (typeof (contactEntry['gd$email']) != "undefined") {
                                        var emailAddresses = contactEntry['gd$email'];
                                        for (var j = 0; j < emailAddresses.length; j++) {
                                            if (typeof (emailAddresses[j]['address']) != "undefined") {
                                                var emailAddress = emailAddresses[j]['address'];
                                                contact['email'] = emailAddress;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    contacts.push(contact);


                                }
                                // To Print All contacts
                                console.log(contacts);

                                // You can fetch other information as per your requirement uncomment the given line and read the data.
                                //console.log(entries);
                            });

                }
            }
        </script>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
        <button class="getGmailContact">Get My Gmail Contacts</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read [How To Answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).