# How to get contacts from gmail account?

Tags: ios, objective-c, contacts, gmail-api, gtm-oauth2

Previously i was using following service to get my contacts from my Gmail account.
https://github.com/google/gtm-oauth2
But this API uses embedded browser to login and it will going to deprecated in short time.

Now, i need to use new way to authorise use and contacts from gmail account.
I'm able to login in Google account through following service.
https://github.com/google/GTMAppAuth

But by using this service, i'm not able to get Contacts from my gmail account. Can anyone help me out to get rid on this issue?

Comment: Try using [Retrieving all contacts](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts) using the Contacts API. Just run an authorized request https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full. If you're using javascript, check this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124828/get-gmail-contacts-google-contacts-api-with-javascript) for code sample reference.

Answer (score 0):

For gmail contacts, I have been using python to access the people API.

Google provides an apiclient and oauth2client to manage the entire application flow.

https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/python

Once you have retrieved credentials, you can call the people service

https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/

In python, you could try method results =

service.people().connections().list(resourceName='people/me', pageSize=10).execute()

connections = results.get('connections', [])

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for looking for this issue. After digging more with below services i got solution.

- https://github.com/google/gtm-oauth2
- https://github.com/google/GTMAppAuth
- https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/

It is giving everything just we need to read carefully. They also giving good sample project which serve everything what we need.

Comment: Can you share your solution for iOS swift. I sort of solved it upto android using - https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/java

Comment: I tried GTMAppAuth example and was able to fetch user's profile but when I tried to fetch the contacts I always get 403-Forbidden error, I followed the guide to fetch contacts and also asked for proper permissions, but I'm always getting the same error.